# ansi-terminal and native io manager doesn't work

Tags: windows, haskell, multiprocessing

i'm using 2 functions simultaneously, one that takes input with getChar and other that draws some characters con the terminal, however, i'm using **ansi-terminal** to move the cursor on the screen
the problem is that when i compile throws the next error

```
user error (pattern match failure in do expression at libraries\Win32\System\Win32\Types.hsc
```

this only happens when i set "+RTS --io-manager=native" flag, but that is necesary 'cause getChar doesn's work properly without it

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in version 2.12.0.1 of `Win32`. See [this issue](https://github.com/haskell/win32/issues/177).

If you're using cabal I think you can make a `cabal.project` file with these contents:

```
packages: .

constraints: Win32 >= 2.12.0.1
```

Or if you use stack I believe you can add `Win32-2.12.0.1` to your `extra-deps` in your `stack.yaml`.

Comment: is there a way to specify this to the compiler without using cabal or stack?

Comment: @monadicAutomaton If you have already installed the package in your package database then you should be able to run `ghc -package Win32-2.12.0.1 YourFile.hs`, but installing a package into a package database is the easiest via cabal or stack, so I would really recommend that. You can read about all the details in [this part of the GHC documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html).